# When looking for 3 factors of value $x$ - what can one say about the number range where the factors must be in?

Tags: factoring, integer-partitions

I want to find the 3 positive integer factors of a given positive integer $x$, such as

$a \cdot b \cdot c = x$

What can I say in what integer number range $a$ and $b$ must be in? (Of course, $c$ is the result of $x/(a \cdot b)$)

I.e. when looking for $a \cdot b = c$ for given $c$, it is clear that $1 \leqslant a \leqslant \sqrt c$.

But where do I have to look for $a$ and $b$ (for a given $x$)?

Thanks!

Comment: you can definitely argue that at least one of the numbers should be at most $x^{1/3}$.

Comment: Thanks -- if *a* is less than x^1/3 -- can we say anything about *b*?

Comment: $b \le (x/a)^{1/2}$